# How to add/extend an object in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In vue.js, you can iterate over an array of items in your template like so:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, i) in items">i: item</div>
</div>

<script>
  var example2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: ['one', 'two', 'three']
    }
  })
</script>
```

Through experimentation, I also discovered you can do something similar with an object instead of an array:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items">i: item</div>
</div>

<script>
  var example2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      items: {one: 'one', two: 'two', three: 'three'}
    }
  })
</script>
```

If you want to add to the array, you can do something like `example2.items.push('four')`, and vue.js will react by inserting another DOM element. However, how would you go about inserting another item into an object instead in such a way that vue.js will react the same as it did to the array? You can't use the push method because it's not available to a generic object, so 
I'm left trying something like:

```
example2.items.four = 'four'
```

But vue.js doesn't detect that change, so no new element is inserted into the DOM. My question is: **How can i insert a new object ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `set` like this:

```
this.$set(this.myObject, 'newKey', { cool: 'its my new object' })
```

You could use `Object.assign` too:

```
let newObject = { newKey: { cool: 'its my new object' }}
this.myObject = Object.assign({}, this.myObject, newObject)
```

More: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Had to wait 6 minutes before it would let me accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I asked too soon. I found the following documentation that answers my question. "Object Change Detection Caveats," found here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html